# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'first'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a database in my terminal but when I try it I always get this error when I use `from first import db`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'first'
```

Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    Title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable= False)
    Content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable= False)
    Date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable= False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Blog Post" + str(self.id)


all_posts = [

    {
        'Title': 'Post 1',
        'Content': "This is the first content"

     },
    {
        'Title': 'Post 2',
        'Content': 'This is the second content'
    }
]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/blog-posts')
def blog_posts():
    return render_template("posts.html", posts = all_posts)


@app.route('/home')
def hello():
    return "My first python website"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

I only have python 3.8 installed.

What could be the problem? I've searched the internet and used every advice on other platforms yet no solution. Flask and flask-sqlalchemy are installed properly.

This is the youtube video I use as a guide when creating this project:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mwFC4SHY-Y

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `from first import db`?

Comment: Without knowing if you created a virtual environment for your script, did you activate it before? And did you ensure, that you're in the same directory as the script itself? Small advice: you use capitalized variables within your class BlogPost. Variables generally shoud be all lowercase. Common practise is to use uppercase only for constants and camel case for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am assuming you have created a python file named `first`. I am listing out what could have been gone wrong:

1. You are in the wrong directory.
2. You have not installed the necessary package. (unlikely)
3. According to the tutorial, the file name is `app.py` so there he performs `from app import db`. Just make sure you have the name of the file correct.

I am not able to think of any other probable cause, unless `first` is a package create by you to store the project's  python files like `routes.py`, `models.py`, etc. In that case you need to have `__init__.py` file in the package directory and initialize `app` and `db`  in `__init__.py` file